# Approximately calculating structure of modes in a waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations, dielectric, waveguide

I know this a super open-ended question, but I hope I can get something out of it anyway.

Here is a crude diagram of the cross section of a waveguide I am simulating on COMSOL:

[image]

and here is the output I get from COMSOL for the norm of the electric field:

[image]

Now, this *looks* right, but I can't really explain why it could be right apart from saying that it looks confined.

I have taken EM classes and we have dealt with simple planar waveguides and I could guess the shape of a given mode before running the simulation.

Could someone suggest a way to get some intuition behind arbitrary simple structures like this so that I can look at the output and go *"hey, that is similar to what I was expecting"*?

TL;DR - How I can approximately guess mode shapes in waveguides before simulating them?

Comment: The COMSOL image is pretty but what is it? Needs labelled axis, IMO...

Comment: @Gert, dang it. I knew I was missing something. The plot is the norm of the electric field. We are looking at the cross section of the waveguide. The waveguide is perpendicular to the plane and infinite in length. Unfortunately, I don't have access to my computer now. I'll add more details as soon as I can. Positive x axis to the right, positive y upwards and positive z into the plane.  Also, please let me know if you want any other specific details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you calculate the cut-off modes separately as those can be calculated from a single scalar function that satisfies a variable coefficient 2D Helmholtz's equation.
Below I use the $x,y,z$ rectangular coordinates, the transverse plane $x,y$ is denoted by the subscript $t$, the axis of propagation is $\hat z$ and the waveguide is homogeneous along $z$.

For example, here is the so-called cut-off TE mode whose generating scalar function is $\psi \propto H_z $:

$$\nabla_t (\epsilon_r ^{-1} \nabla_t \psi) + \kappa^2 \psi = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$ with $\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial n}=0$ at the outer boundary and $$\mathbf{E}_t = \epsilon_r^{-1} \hat z \times \nabla_t \psi \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$H_z=-\mathfrak j \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_0}{\mu_0}} \kappa \psi \tag{3}\label{3}$$
$$H_t=0,E_z=0\tag{4}\label{4}$$

The cut-off quasi TM mode is generated by the scalar $\phi \propto E_z$ and

$$\nabla^2_t \phi + \kappa^2 \epsilon_r\phi = 0 \tag{5}\label{5}$$ with $\phi=0$ at the outer boundary and $$\mathbf{H}_t =  \hat z \times \nabla_t \phi \tag{6}\label{6}$$
$$E_z=\mathfrak j \sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}} \kappa \phi \tag{7}\label{7}$$
$$E_t=0,H_z=0\tag{8}\label{8}$$

Notice that *at* cut-off the fields separate into exact *transversal* TE and TM modes, and it is fair to assume that *near* cut-off the fields are nearly TE or TM, hence the name quasi. So calculate the cut-off modes separately and use that as a first order approximation of the *propagating* fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is sort of what I was looking for. I'll wait till tomorrow to accept it. Upvoted for now.

Comment: May I ask what $\epsilon_r^{-1}$ stands for? Is $\epsilon$ a function? If so, of what? Ta.

Comment: $\epsilon_r$ is the medium's relative permittivity, $\epsilon_r ^{-1}=1/\epsilon_r$. I assumed that $\mu_r=1$ throughout and there is an ideal metal wall enclosing the waveguide "far" from the axis so there is no radiation.

Comment: Ok. That was a bit of a dumb question: I'm a bit rusty on EM and the HE. So where are the *variable coefficient 2D Helmholtz's equation*? I'll +1 this if you explain the used symbols a bit. It's a nice answer.

Comment: @Gert In this waveguide problem the permittivity $\epsilon_r$ is *not* a constant in either eq. 1 or eq. 5; air, SiN, substrate have different permittivity. If it were  a constant we would have the usual Helmholtz equation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation and the usual (true) TE/TM solutions for all frequencies. Which symbols are unclear still?

Comment: Hi. With this context all is clear to me now. I might formulate my own answer. +1 from me. Ta.

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is not a constant then it is a function of what?

Comment: @Gert $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r(x,y) $

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this could be due to a few definition issues:

- You are defining the boundaries at the edges of your already bounded system is: While strictly this is a "quirk" of not being able to define infinitely extended media (e.g. a substrate that is much larger than your medium of interest, in this case, the SiN waveguide with respect to the silica substrate and the air). Therefore, COMSOL has a definition for those boundaries and solves appropriately.

  - The best way to resolve this is to remove any unnecessary boundaries as they will also be solved and have a valid, convergent solution.
- The mode analysis is searching for too many modes. This can be somewhat connected to the previous point, but when I was not restricting the solution to the refractive index of interest (SiN at your operating wavelength) a lot of modes which solve the equation are output to the solver.

  - In the Study settings under "mode analysis", change the "Search for modes around" and the refractive index of the core of the waveguide (SiN) at the wavelength of interest.
- I added an additional exclusion to my studies in the "combine solutions" step of my study, where "model.ewfd.neff < n_air" where *.neff is an output of the Electromagnetic Waves, Frequency Domain (ewfd) solver, and "n_air" is a variable I defined in the "Global definitions" of my Model Builder (this value is a scalar which you can define by itself or through a function, depending on how extended your studies will be).

  - This has the advantage of discarding a lot of computationally valid but physically meaningless modes and makes sharing the simulation better as you don't have to explain "n" number of "quirky results" and make it easier to explain.