# Field at exactly cutoff of optical fiber

Tags: fiber-optics

Can anyone give a clear qualitative explanation on what is the field inside and outside an optical fiber at EXACTLY cutoff?

Comment: if the fiber is enclosed in a metallic jacket that is as far away from the core as possible, so it cannot radiate, then the field is transversal TE or transversal TM derivable form a single scalar function; here are some details https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/680545/approximately-calculating-structure-of-modes-in-a-waveguide/680568#680568

Comment: If there is a propagating field in the fiber, then why it is called cutoff?

Comment: because it is not propagating but is more like "static" for can be generated from a potential similarly to electro or magneto-static fields

Comment: But TM and TE are propagating modes? What do you mean "static"

Comment: E or M static fields can be generated from a single potential function. At cut-off, but  only at cut-off you can do the same by solving for either $H_z$ or $E_z$. The former gives TE and $E_z=0$, the latter gives TM that is $H_z=0$. Read the link. These do not propagate along the z-axis but do fluctuate in time, hence it is not static field but in one respect, ie.e, having a scalar function acting as a potential it behaves as if it were from teat point of view.

Comment: Note: The cut-off field is completely homogeneous along the z-axis, it does fluctuate in time but all spatial variations are in the cross-sectional (transversal) plane.

Comment: Does this means resonance in the cross section?

Comment: yes, you can view it that way

Comment: Ok thank you bro, you were very helpful!